# iOS: prevent segue when alert is showing

Tags: ios

I have the following UI elements:

- A table view cell with an associated segue
- A save button that shows an alert if data is missing

A table view cell's segue does not run until the user lets go of the button. So they can do the following:

- Tap and hold the cell
- While holding cell, tap the save button
- Let go of cell

This brings up the alert and performs the segue behind it! Seems like iOS should not run the segue, but at least on iOS 10 it allows this behavior. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: From a User experience point of view you should not enable the save button until all of the data is present.

Comment: You should in fact not use a simple segue in this sense, and connect the cell with a delegate which checks the relative data is available first.

Comment: you need to dismiss alert with its clicked button action.

Comment: @Paulw11 Disabling the Save button was not appropriate in this case, because we want to explain to the user what data is missing. This is a valid approach that many other apps use. It is not a simple form so there is no place to show an informative warning message.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I find associated segues to be elegant and convenient at times. I see little difference in complexity between doing the segue manually and using `shouldPerformSegue`.

Comment: @KKRocks Dismissing the alert and performing the segue would be an equally valid solution. In our case preventing the segue seemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your view controller:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return presentedViewController == nil
}
```

This will prevent any segue when a modal view controller is presented.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5009924547411968

Comment: Why the downvote? Are you seeking more explanation about how the code works?

Comment: Its not a solid solution, if someone else was to use this solution, it could casue unwanted functionality, it is a solution to your specific UI configuration not the question

Comment: @SeanLintern88 This code will stop segues from performing when a modal view controller is showing. It is not specific to my configuration, since `presentedViewController` is a property of UIViewController. No segue should ever be performed when a modal view is showing, so this code is safe in all circumstances.